# Operator = overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

Let's say I have this:

```
struct coor
{
   int x;
   int y;
   COORD operator=(coor c)
   {
      COORD C={c.x,c.y}
      return C;
   }
}
```

and I needed to do:

```
coor c={0,0};
COORD C=c;
```

I could add operator overloading to `coor`, but how do you do that to return to left side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator `=` must assign values to members of the object itself. The return value is there just to make `a = b = c` and similar things work. In your case it is irrelevant. Also, if you have `A = B`, the `=` defined in `A` will be used and if you have `B = A`, the `=` in `B` is used.
What you need is to write a `=` in `COORD` that takes `coor` parameter and updates members of this.

And the following does not call operator`=`:

```
COORD C=c;
```

It calls a matching constructor.

and the operator= MUST return `*this` for things like this: `a=b=c=d` to work but this is conventional

Answer (score 1):

```
struct coor
{
   int x;
   int y;
   COORD operator=(coor c)
   {
      COORD C;
      C.x = c.x;
      C.y = c.y;
      return C;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To overload the `operator=` so that it assigns a `coor` object to a `COORD` object, you must do that inside the `COORD` `struct`:

```
struct COORD
{
    int x;
    int y;
    COORD& operator=(coor& c)
    {
        this->x = c.x;
        this->y = c.y;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

However, as others mentioned, this overloading is applied to assignments like:

```
coor c = {0,0};
COORD C;
C = c;
```

But not for

```
coor c = {0,0};
COORD C = c;
```

As the second line is actually a calling of a constructor of COORD which takes an object of `coor` as an argument. The body could look something like:

```
COORD(coor c):x(c.x),y(c.y)
{
}
```